# Repeat numbers according to pattern numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array, say `p = [2,3,2,4]` and a number, say `n = 4`. I need to generate an array of ones and zeros according to the pattern p, n-p. That is for each element, u in p, there are u ones followed by n-u zeros. It's very easy to do this using the np.insert operation. But theano doesn't have any insert op. Is it possible to achieve this without using a loop? Also, given multiple such ps and corresponding ns, is it possible to generate the ones and zeros patterns without using a loop?
Here's an example:
1 value of p:

```
p = [2,3,2,4,1], n=4
n-p = [2,1,2,0,3]
result = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

multiple values of p: In this case all p's will have same dimension(p is a 2D array)

```
p = [[2,3,2,4,1],[2,2,3,5,4]], n = [4, 5]
n-p = [[2,1,2,0,3],[3,3,2,0,1]]
result = [[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
```

Please note that I've padded result[0] with 0s at the end to match the dimensions of result[0] and result[1]

Comment: can you post output for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p = numpy.array([2, 3, 2, 4])
n = 4
result = (p[:, None] > numpy.arange(n)).ravel().astype(int)
```

We compare

```
[[2]
 [3]
 [2]
 [4]]
```

to `[0 1 2 3]` to get an array of booleans, then flatten it and convert it to integers to get the output you want.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this to a two dimensional case? That is when multiple p arrays are given?

Comment: @Aditya369: I don't know. Fixing up the lengths for different `n` values seems hard to do in an efficient way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to pad the arrays of p itself with zeros? Or set these elements as values of a bigger array? Because if n = [4,5] and p.shape[1]=4, we know the maximum size is going to be 5*4=20. So we create a 2D array of size (p.shape[0], 20) and set the results into this array?

Comment: @Aditya369: Trying to pad `p` itself would require the rows to have different lengths, and you'd run into problems with the output axis length not being divisible by all `n` values anyway.